# NumberFormatter in SwiftUI - Use of unresolved identifier 'formatter'

Tags: ios, swift, formatting, swiftui, number-formatting

In my SwiftUI app I will need to work with currencies. I am trying to use NumberFormatter, but getting an error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'formatter'

on line:

```
self.valueAsString = formatter.string(for: self.value)
```

Here is the code I have:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var newValueAsString = ""
    @State private var value: NSDecimalNumber = 0
    @State private var valueAsString = "0.0"
    
    let decimalBehavior = NSDecimalNumberHandler(roundingMode: .plain, scale: 2, raiseOnExactness: false, raiseOnOverflow: false, raiseOnUnderflow: false, raiseOnDivideByZero: true)
    
    private var currencyFormat: NumberFormatter = {
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.usesSignificantDigits = true
        formatter.minimumSignificantDigits = 1 // default
        formatter.maximumSignificantDigits = 6 // default
        return formatter
    }()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("0", text: $newValueAsString, onCommit: {
                self.value = NSDecimalNumber(string: self.newValueAsString, locale: Locale.current).rounding(accordingToBehavior: self.decimalBehavior)
                self.valueAsString = formatter.string(for: self.value)
                // Tried this too:
                //  self.valueAsString = "\(formatter.string(for: self.value))"
            }
            )
                .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                .font(Font.system(size: 30))
                .keyboardType(.decimalPad)
            
            // Just to test. Later I will save the value to Core Data.
            Text("\(self.value)")
            Text("\(self.valueAsString)")
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

What I wanted to do:

1. Declare rules for currencyFormat using NumberFormatter.
2. Write a value (newValueAsString) as String into the TextField.
3. On Commit, newValueAsString is changed to NSDecimalNumber and
   assigned to self.value.
4. Change NSDecimalNumber value back to String (valueAsString) using
   formatter rules. **Here I am getting an error.**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you meant

```
self.valueAsString = self.currencyFormat.string(for: self.value)
```

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you :) I just edited your answer to add `?? "0"` to provide default for optional value